# How can you ever buy a development card with 14 tokens?

Tags: splendor

How can you ever buy a development card with 14 tokens? as you can never reach this amount, even when you draw +3 on your turn, the max you can reach is 13, and you cant use them to purchase the card as your tuen is over?

Comment: The max number of tokens you can reach is 10, not 13.  You cannot get tokens and purchase a card on the same turn, and you must always discard down to 10 tokens by the end of your turn.

Comment: @John He says that already at the end of the question; that you could reach 13, but you wouldn't be able to use them to purchase the card.

Answer (score 15):

I don't think players are meant to by a level 3 development card with just gem tokens. As you righty say, buying a development card costing 14 or more with just gem tokens would be impossible. Are you are aware that development cards count as bonuses? If you look at the rules [here](https://cdn.1j1ju.com/medias/7f/91/ba-splendor-rulebook.pdf) they say-

> The bonuses a player has from development cards acquired on previous
>   turns provide discounts on the purchase of new cards. Each bonus of a
>   given color is equal to a token of that color. Thus, if a player has 2
>   blue bonuses and wants to purchase a card which costs 2 blue tokens
>   and 1 green token, the player must only spend 1 green token. If a
>   player has enough development cards (and therefore bonuses), they can
>   even purchase a card without spending any tokens.

So a player can buy a development card costing 14 tokens provided that the cost is reduced by bonuses for previously bought development cards.